# Emacs 24 Keyboard Macros Running Slow

Tags: emacs, emacs23, emacs24

I've noticed keyboard macros running very slowly in emacs 24

for example - I just tried running a macro to append a '0' to the end of each line in a 105615 line text file

```
C-x ( C-e TAB 0 C-n C-a C-x )
```

then

```
C-u 105615 C-x e
```

takes about 5 mins to complete

I never noticed them running so slow before, wondered if it had anything to do with upgrading from 23 to 24?

Is there anything I can do to improve performance?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you measure this kind of thing in Emacs 23? Macros go through the interactive machinery, so they're not efficient with huge repetition counts.

Comment: Tangentially, note that if you want to repeat a macro until the end of the file, you can supply `C-u 0` instead of checking and specifying the actual line count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right, it's damn slow.

For this particular task you can use `replace-regexp`.

```
M-x buffer-disable-undo
M-x replace-regexp $ <ENTER> C-q TAB 0 <ENTER>
```

Comment: I would say so. I use macros to execute them dozes or hundreds of time. For hundreds thousands of time you should look for another solution.

Answer (score 10):

This answer certainly won't always be applicable, but if the major mode happens to be irrelevant for the macro in question, then a good way to improve the execution speed of a keyboard macro is to switch the buffer to *fundamental-mode* first. In some circumstances that can provide dramatic speed increases, as you eliminate the overhead of the major and minor modes.

If changing major modes isn't possible, you may still get a significant benefit from disabling some of the minor modes for the duration.

However, as per the accepted answer & comments, if a search-and-replace will suffice, that will always be far quicker than any macro.

Answer (score 5):

In your keyboard macro I see two potential sources of slowness:

- `TAB`: depending on the major mode, this may perform a lot of work, e.g. to figure out the indentation to use.
- `C-n`: since Emacs-23, this tries to move to the next display line, so it can require a lot more work than before (it has to take into account the display rendering, with details such as variable-width fonts, images, ...).  Also it is not reliable for your use, since on a line longer than the display, it `C-n` will move to the next display line but stay on the same logical line, such that the subsequent `c-a` will just move back to the beginnning of the same line (because `C-a` works on logical lines, not display lines).  Of course, all this depends on `line-move-visual` and `visual-line-mode`.

For the TAB, I don't have a good recommendation because I don't know what it's intended to do (depends on the major mode), but I'd replace `C-n C-a` with `C-f` which will be much faster and more reliable.

Comment: good point i can see C-f would be more succint in this instance, but its still damn slow! I assume oleg's C-q TAB (as opposed to just TAB) bypasses any context specific behaviour for the TAB key

Answer (score 0):

My reading of info suggests that `(forward-line)` may be a better replacement for `C-n C-a` because this ignores any visual line breaks (so may be more efficient), and moves to the start of the line (saving the `C-a`).